# Why reaction with `when` works and with `observe` or `intercept` not?

Tags: mobx

Mobx-utils/fromPromise.state is NOT Observable!

```js
const { observable, when, reaction, intercept, observe, isObservable } = mobx;
const { fromPromise, whenWithTimeout } = mobxUtils;

const promise = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(res => res.json())
const result = fromPromise(promise);

console.assert(isObservable(result.state), 'state is NOT an isObservable');

/* WORKS!
when(
  () => result.state !== "pending",
  () => {
    console.log("Got ", result.value)
  }
);
*/

// NOT WORK, Why ?
observe(result, 'state', change => (console.log('observe', change)), true)
intercept(result, 'state', change => (console.log('intercept', change)));
reaction(
  () => result.state,
  state => console.log('reaction', state)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mobx@3/lib/mobx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mobx-utils/mobx-utils.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result.state` is not observable, but if you take a look at [its implementation](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-utils/blob/master/src/from-promise.ts#L41) you will see that when you do `result.state` it accesses observable `result._state`.

```
private _state: IObservableValue<PromiseState> = observable(PENDING as any);
....
get state(): PromiseState {
    return this._state.get();
}
```

`reaction` and `when` work because they react to `_state` access which happens when you read `state`. This is clearly explained [in the documentation](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html).

`observe` and `intercept` do not work because `result` is not observable. They expect their very **first** parameter to be an **observable**. Hence, even updated code won't work

```
observe(result, '_state', change => (console.log('observe', change)), true)
intercept(result, '_state', change => (console.log('intercept', change)));
```

To fix it pass `result._state` as the first argument.

```
observe(result._state, change => (console.log('observe', change)), true)
intercept(result._state, change => (console.log('intercept', change)));
```